# Ano/Mes/Dia... como fazer

Tags: vba

porem preciso que ele me gere uma pasta de ano, mes e dia
alguem pode me ajudar?
segue...

```
' informacoes 
Public cDay, cMonth, cMonthName, cPath

Function identificarData()

' Identificar o caminho na rede

    cPath = "caminho para salvar o arquivo"

' Identificar o dia e mês

    If Day(Date) < 10 Then

        cDay = "0" & Day(Date)

    Else

        cDay = Day(Date)

    End If

    If Month(Date) + 1 < 10 Then

        cMonth = "0" & Month(Date)

    Else

        cMonth = Month(Date)

    End If

' Identificar o nome do mês

    Select Case cMonth

    Case Is = "01"
        cMonthName = "January"

    Case Is = "02"
        cMonthName = "February"

    Case Is = "03"
        cMonthName = "March"

    Case Is = "04"
        cMonthName = "April"

    Case Is = "05"
        cMonthName = "May"

    Case Is = "06"
        cMonthName = "June"

    Case Is = "07"
        cMonthName = "July"

    Case Is = "08"
        cMonthName = "August"

    Case Is = "09"
        cMonthName = "September"

    Case Is = "10"
        cMonthName = "October"

    Case Is = "11"
        cMonthName = "November"

    Case Is = "12"
        cMonthName = "December"

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Salve, Diego! Poderia usar sentenças completas?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo(a). Por favor faça o [tour], depois leia [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e crie um [mcve] para a pergunta. Pois a pergunta está muito ampla e quando [você é mais específico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104), há mais chances de sua pergunta ser respondida corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um código de demonstração de como gerar o mês e dia para um ano específico. Sugiro rodar o código passo-a-passo para entendê-lo (com a tecla F8).

### Código

```
Dim Ano As Date, Data As Date
Dim i As Long, DiasNoMes As Long, j As Long
Ano = 2018
j = 0
'Teste Imprimir Meses
For i = 1 To 12
    Debug.Print DateSerial(Ano, i, 1) 'Ou
    'MsgBox DateSerial(Ano, i, 1)
    'Usar Debug.Print ou MsgBox
    Debug.Print Format(DateSerial(Ano, i, 1), "MMMM")

    'Dias no mês
    DiasNoMes = Day(DateSerial(Ano, i + 1, 0))
    Debug.Print DiasNoMes

    'Loop para criar cada dia do mês
    For j = 1 To DiasNoMes
        Debug.Print j
        Debug.Print DateSerial(Ano, i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

### Explicação

- Inserir 2018 como ano: `Ano = 2018`
- Loop nos 12 meses do ano: `For i = 1 To 12:Next i`
- A data do primeiro dia do mês do loop no formato dd/mm/aaaa: `Debug.Print DateSerial(Ano, i + 1, 0)`
- O mês escrito por extenso:  `Debug.Print Format(DateSerial(Ano, i, 1), "MMMM")`
- A quantidade de dias do mês: `DiasNoMes = Day(DateSerial(Ano, i + 1, 0))`
- Loop em cada dia do mês: `For j = 1 To DiasNoMes:Next j`

> Obs.: Para visualizar o que é impresso com o comando `Debug.Print`, é preciso habilitar a janela de Verificação Imediata.