# Mostrar valor diluído de acordo com o último dia do mês! Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Exemplo][1] [1]: http://prntscr.com/jsd694
1 - investimento pelo cliente;
2 - inicio do contrato;
3 - duração do contrato;
4 - taxa de rendimento para cada cliente;
5 - se o cliente optou por retirar o rendimento mensalmente ou não;
6 - valor a ser depositado mensalmente para os que optaram por depósito mensal;
7 - Data de termino do contrato;
8 - valor final a ser retirado no final do contrato;
9 - taxa administrativa cobrada em cada retirada;
10 - quantos dias ja decorreram da data do contrato;(=($A$1-C3))
11 - conversão do item 10 para meses;(foi a única forma que achei para ter o resultado do ítem 12)(=K3/(365/12))
12 - me da o quanto ja rendeu desde o início de seu contrato; (=B3*(((1+E3)^L3)-1))
13 - o problema esta aqui; os clientes q optam por retiradas mensais terão o mesmo valor todo mês, exp R$ 10000,00 a 8% = R$800,00 todo mês, porem preciso diluir este valor para cada dia do mês, e me retornar o rendimento do dia primeiro até o dia atual, e quando virar o mês recomeça tudo de novo.

Comment: Valor_total / ( hoje() - datainicio ) = valor_diario

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

`=SE($F2<>"Não";($F2/(DIA(DATA(ANO(HOJE());MÊS(HOJE())+1;0))))*DIA(HOJE());"")`

#### Explicação

Se a coluna F for diferente da string "Não", divide o valor de F2 pelo número de dias do mês e multiplica pelo dia de hoje.
Caso contrário, escreve vazio ""

### Resposta Original

Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/303087/75104) em que mostra como verificar a quantidade de dias em cada mês de um ano

Para transformar a mesma fórmula de VBA de dias no mês `DiasNoMes = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date)+1, 0))`

Para Excel fórmula, esta função pode ser usada: `=DIA(DATA(ANO(HOJE());MÊS(HOJE())+1;0))` ou `=DIA(DATA(ANO(HOJE());MÊS(HOJE())+1;1)-1)`

Portanto, a seguinte fórmula irá na célula de rendimento diário:

`=10000/DIA(DATA(ANO(HOJE());MÊS(HOJE()+1);0))`, em que 10000 pode ser a célula que contém este valor (ex.: $G5)

Comment: cara ... vc é o cara ... top d mais! no caso serão pessoas diferentes com valores diferentes onde a data de inicio será diferente! posso substituir hoje() pela celula q esta o hoje()?

Comment: Campeão, desculpa mas acho q acabei esquecendo de mencionar um detalhe, como o resultado mostrou o rendimento diluído, seria muito complicado fazer ele se somando dia após dia de acordo com o dia do mês? por exp. como hj é dia 6, então já seria somado 6x a fração e o resultado a ser mostrado seria 199,99.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, poderia criar um [mcve]?

Comment: Verificável? Não sei como fazer isso. Tenho um empresa, e estamos no começo das nossas atividades, não tenho como disponibilizar capital contratando uma empresa para desenvolver um sistema, portanto uma planilha de acompanhamento da me ajuda muito. na Imagem, na formula coloquei x 7 pois seria o dia atual. http://prntscr.com/js4taw

Comment: @Marcelo Veja o edit

Comment: Daniel Muito Obrigado, foi perfeito. Desculpe qqr inconveniente!

Comment: Favor ler [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)